# How to evaluate the predicted probabilities given by XGboost?

Tags: python, statistics, probability, random-forest, xgboost

I have an imbalanced binary classification problem. The ratio for positive to negative class is about 1:10. I trained an XGBoost tree model to predict these two classes using continuous and categorical data as input.

Using [this XGBoost library](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html), I predict the probability of new inputs using `predict_proba`. I am assuming the probability values output here is the *likelihood* of these new test data being the positive class? Say I have an entire test set with test labels, how am I able to evaluate the quality of these (I'm assuming) likelihoods?

Comment: Classifier outputs are typically the posterior class probabilities p(c | x). I would expect that's what XGBoost predict_proba outputs, at least approximately. Typically continuous classifier outputs are evaluated via an ROC curve.

Comment: You can compute the [LogLoss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) between test labels and predictions. The lower logloss the better. There are many other metrics that you can use the assess the model performance. Maybe the simplest is the [Accuracy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), but you will need predicted labeld. You can also try MLJAR AutoML approach https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised - the AutoML will compute many metrics values for you, without too much coding.